# PHP Undefined Variable, yet the script works perfect, if I define the variable it does not work

Tags: php, variables, undefined

I have a problem with an undefined variable, if I define the variable the script does not work correctly, I know it's a simple answer I just can't find it.

Here is my code: ( I use this in a for each loop )

```
$weight= ($item['weight']*$item['quantity']);  
$totalweight = ($totalweight + $weight) 

echo $totalweight;
```

The script works perfect and gives me the correct answerexcept I get an undefined variable error on line 2 $totalweight

I have tried to set the variable it then breaks the calculation.

Comment: That code makes no sense. If you know `$totalweight` doesn't exist why do you have `($totalweight + $weight) `???

Comment: What's the point of the second line if the variable is unassigned?

Comment: how are you suppose to do $totalweight = ($totalweight + $weight), if $totalweight isn't defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to initialize the variable *outside* of the loop so it's not overwritten on every iteration:

```
$totalweight = 0;
foreach ($items as $item) {
    $weight= ($item['weight']*$item['quantity']);  
    $totalweight = ($totalweight + $weight) 
}

echo $totalweight;
```

Comment: You hit the nail on the head, I was trying to definfe the variable inside the loop

Answer (score 0):

How are you setting the variable? PHP is producing this notice because you are asking it to add `$totalWeight` and `$weight` and it doesn't know what `$totalWeight` is.

To remove this notice you could do:

```
$totalWeight = 0;
$weight= ($item['weight']*$item['quantity']);  
$totalweight = ($totalweight + $weight);

echo $totalweight;
```

Although it's probably just best to change the line to be:

```
$totalweight = $weight;
```

(Unless of course this code runs in a loop or the like).